# Can a component allow multiple ng-content with the same selector?

Tags: angular5

I am working on a component that serves as a "step by step form" but I do not know how to allow a component (stepper) to receive several contents (step) and be able to manipulate them.

An example of what I finally want is:

Stepper Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper',
  template: `
<div class="stepper-container">
    <ng-content select="step" #steps></ng-content>
</div>
`
})
```

And use like:

```
<stepper>
  <step>Hola  soy un step</step>
  <step>Hola  soy otro step</step>
  <step>Y yo otro step</step>
</stepper>
```

Comment: can you add more details about what you're doing?  If I understand you correctly there's quite a few ways to do this, it's just a matter of which one best suits the purpose.

Comment: After a coffee I realized that I should only manage the children elements of the component. I took all the step elements and showed them or hide them according to the selected step

Comment: ok.  I was going to suggest adding `ngIf` conditions to the containers if each section was fairly small.  If they were more in depth I'd say create more components to keep them organized.